# Is "What do you expect from your partner" equivalent to "expected partner?"?

Tags: word-choice

I dont want to use long sentence like this "What do you expect from your partner?".

Can i use "expected partner?" instead?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. Are you asking whether the sentence "What do you expect from your partner?" is equivalent to the sentence, "Expected partner?" (which really isn't a sentence at all).  About the shortest I can come up with is: "What're your partner expectations?"

Comment: done, updated the question

Comment: Is this a prompt on a form? in which case "Partner Expectations:" might work. If it's not for a form, where will this be used?

Comment: "Expectation about Partner" could be the right one. Thaxnk you for your hint

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to imagine any context in which the short phrase is a reasonable substitute for the complete sentence.